# My main User directory is gone, how can I get it back?

Tags: macos, time-machine, user, user-accounts

If I open up my hard drive and navigate to Users, my main account is not there. How can I get it back?

In retrospect I realize it has been gone for a while, but since it still appears in the Sidebar I haven't worried too much about it. Until I recently realized that all my Time Machine backups are worthless because I can't navigate to any files backed up within my account (if I check the file size of the backup it's the same size as what's on my hard drive, so I know it's actually there, I just can't get to it).

I've tried creating an alias to the account but it won't let me do that through the Sidebar. I've searched all over the place and haven't seen another post like this. Anyone have any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Here you can see my user account on the left with the 'M', but going through `HD > Users` my account isn't there.

The 'M' account is where all my stuff is, other added accounts appear under `Users` like the 'L' account.

[image: missing user account]

Daniel,
Your suggestion returned this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and entering `ls -la /Users`? Is there maybe a directory named `.mainusername`?

Comment: Running your suggestion returned what is in the image above. I'm seeing the user account, but not as '.M' Does this help?

Comment: @Farley One thing I notice is that account shouldn't have `wheel` as its group. I also don't recall User home folders having the `@` attribute. My first suggestion would be to go to /Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility.app, click your hard drive and then "Repair Disk Permissions".

Comment: Try running `ls -la@ /Users`, and `chflags nohidden /Users/M` (of course entering the whole user name). If the latter fails, try `sudo chflags nohidden /Users/M` and enter your user account password if you're on an administrator account. What happens when you log in to the M account? Is it even possible? Open *System Preferences, Accounts, select M, right-click, Advanced*, and check where its home directory is configured.

Comment: Also, since you're apparently new here: slhck and I just commented on your question, which doesn't bump it to the start of the front page; only answers do. If you respond to specific users in comments, write `@username`, e.g. @Farley or @Daniel -- then that user gets notified by the system, just like you were notified of my comment. Remember to click the green checkmark next to a satisfactory answer below, once you get one: This will reward the user who posted that answer.

Comment: slhck - I've ran this in the past without many repairs. This time it's saying it will take 49 minutes. I'll be back. Thanks.

Comment: @slhck Notifying you of Farley's response.

Comment: @Farley It probably won't take that long. If it doesn't work, try @Daniels solution, it might be the folder has a "hidden" attribute set that prevents it from being seen in the GUI. Moreover, can you actually do the following in Terminal? `cd /Users/M;ls -la;open .` (of course, again with your full username). You should get a list of your home folder in the Terminal, and a Finder window with its contents should show up.

Comment: @Daniel Beck @slhck The home directory is right where it should be, Users/M. The `sudo chflags nohidden /Users/M` did the trick. Thank you!  Is the home folder with the `@` and the group as `wheel` something I should be concerned with?  Sorry, yes I'm new, I'm brushing up on Markdown Editing now.

Comment: run `xattr /Users/M` and tell us what the [extended attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes) names are. I wouldn't be concerned about the group membership, but maybe @slhck thinks a `chown M:staff /Users/M` is in order?

Comment: @Farley The `@` is nothing to be concerned about. The `wheel` user's group too, I just didn't recall seeing it before, rather `staff`. But I wouldn't touch that unless you experience any problems.

Comment: @Farley The '@' symbol means there are extended attributes to the directory/file. You can run ls -la@ to see the extended attributes if you are interested, but as slhck said, I suggest that you open Disk Utility and "Repair Disk Permissions".

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. Please click the checkmark next to it to mark this question answered and send a few reputation points my way. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Beck  `xattr` code returned nothing, just back to the prompt.

Comment: @Farley Is the `@` gone since you ran the `chflags` command? In that case, the only attribute was for Finder to hide the directory, and that has been removed by `chflags`.

Comment: @Daniel Beck the `@` is gone since `chflags` was run. Thanks! You've all been _insanely_ helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file or folder doesn't show up in Finder, and does *not* have a name starting with `.`, then its `hidden` attribute is set.

Unset it in Terminal using the following command:

```
chflags nohidden /path/to/folder/or/file
```

<sup>The `hidden` attribute is actually pretty useful for folders you don't want showing up in Finder, e.g. `/opt` if you use e.g. Homebrew for Unix/Linux software management on your Mac, Music, Pictures, and Movies in your home directory if these are managed by iLife apps anyway, Desktop or Sites if you don't use them, etc.</sup>

Comment: Well spotted :) Now the only question is *why* it was hidden in the first place.

Comment: @slhck Indeed. Since I didn't know how to unhide it, It would be nice to know how that happened in the first place.